# Authenticate google token id with Socialite

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, laravel-socialite

I've received `token-id` from client android app which is generated by google.
How do I authorize the user with socialite?
I'm using google_api client now but it hasn't the convenience of Socialte.

Answer (score 3):

If you can obtain a server auth code then you can exchange it for an accessToken and use it to query the Google+ API.

In my case, I am using a cordova library

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

This will give you (if configured for 'offline') a `serverAuthCode`

You can send that up to your server.  Then, to convert it to an accessToken you can call this socialite method:

```
$driver = Socialite::driver($provider); // provider is 'google' here
$access_token = $driver->getAccessToken($serverAuthCode);
```

Then you can get the user info using this token:

```
$socialUser = $driver->userFromToken($access_token);
```

Just wanted to help anyone else who was struggling with this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but `serverAuthCode ` needs to be verified as well, no?

Comment: That is verified via `$driver->getAccessToken($serverAuthCode)`

Comment: I am inclined to think so, even though I cannot find any docs to confirm. The only problem with this method is the consent screen will ask for offline permissions and some user could be wondering what the heck.

Comment: For older versions please use ```getAccessTokenResponse``` instead,

Comment: @StevenM I am doing what you suggesting but I get a 401 error.  Weird thing is that if I generate the authCode from the same environment it works (if I generate it from local web it works on local web, if I generate if from production web it works on production web). Btw I am using an older version, so I use `getAccessTokenResponse` as @JuliSmz suggests

Comment: The `getAccessToken()` does not seem to exist. Not sure if it has been removed.

Answer (score 3):

Using PHP Google API Client Library

First install library via composer

**$ composer require google/apiclient**

```
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => env('Google_CLIENT_ID')]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
  $userid = $payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}
```

for more details check that

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth?authuser=2

Answer (score 0):

if you want get userinfo you must use accessToken (sometimes need openid) to get it,recently i made a laravel package to fullfill this request, check here :

https://github.com/Ray-Cheng/laravel-socialite-api

Comment: I have the access token,Actually I have validated with google api too, How do I get the info now?

Comment: @Mehrdad,did you check my package?the idea is client side get access token after oauth login,then pass access token to server side,and with my package you can get user infos.

Comment: yeah tnx, but you know,I'm already using Socialit with google api. I don't wanna actually depend on another library because I think that is possible to get the result without it. cheers :)

Comment: And did you come up with a solution? if so please share